# How do I get liquibase cli to rollback changeSets initiated by another app?

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

My database changelog looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <changeSet id="10" author="ez">
        <createTable tableName="SomeTable">
            <column name="someCol" type="int" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="20" author="ez">
        <tagDatabase tag="0.0.1"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="30" author="ez">
        <createTable tableName="AnotherTable">
            <column name="anotherCol" type="int" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="40" author="ez">
        <tagDatabase tag="0.0.2"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

and my `liquibase.propeties` looks like this:

```
changeLogFile=changelog.xml
url=jdbc:mysql://[redacted]@localhost:3306/[redacted]
```

When I run the liquibase migration through code like this:
`Liquibase("classpath:db/liquibase/changelog.xml", ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), db).update(Contexts())` it migrates fine.

But when I try to rollback via CLI like this: `C:\Projects\[redacted]\src\main\resources\db\liquibase>java -jar "C:\Program Files\liquibase\liquibase.jar" --classpath=mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar rollbackSQL 0.0.1`, I get the following SQL:

```
--  *********************************************************************
--  Rollback to '0.0.1' Script
--  *********************************************************************
--  Change Log: changelog.xml
--  Ran at: 1/12/21 4:36 PM
--  Against: user@[redacted]@jdbc:mysql://[redacted]@localhost:3306/[redacted]
--  Liquibase version: 4.2.2
--  *********************************************************************

--  Lock Database
UPDATE `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET `LOCKED` = 1, LOCKEDBY = '[redacted]', LOCKGRANTED = '2021-01-12 16:36:46.435' WHERE ID = 1 AND `LOCKED` = 0;

--  Release Database Lock
UPDATE `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET `LOCKED` = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
```

If I recreate an empty database and run the update through the CLI instead and then try the same rollback command, I get the full rollback SQL:

```
--  *********************************************************************
--  Rollback to '0.0.1' Script
--  *********************************************************************
--  Change Log: changelog.xml
--  Ran at: 1/12/21 4:40 PM
--  Against: user@[redacted]@jdbc:mysql://[redacted]@localhost:3306/[redacted]
--  Liquibase version: 4.2.2
--  *********************************************************************

--  Lock Database
UPDATE `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET `LOCKED` = 1, LOCKEDBY = '[redacted]', LOCKGRANTED = '2021-01-12 16:40:20.982' WHERE ID = 1 AND `LOCKED` = 0;

--  Rolling Back ChangeSet: changelog.xml::40::ez
DELETE FROM `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE ID = '40' AND AUTHOR = 'ez' AND FILENAME = 'changelog.xml';

--  Rolling Back ChangeSet: changelog.xml::30::ez
DROP TABLE `[redacted]`.AnotherTable;

DELETE FROM `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE ID = '30' AND AUTHOR = 'ez' AND FILENAME = 'changelog.xml';

--  Rolling Back ChangeSet: changelog.xml::20::ez
DELETE FROM `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE ID = '20' AND AUTHOR = 'ez' AND FILENAME = 'changelog.xml';

--  Release Database Lock
UPDATE `[redacted]`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET `LOCKED` = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
```

What gives? How do I rollback the changeSets made by my app via the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Liquibase rollback from command line not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147769/liquibase-rollback-from-command-line-not-working)

When I run it from my app, the FILENAME in the DATABASECHANGELOG is `db/liquibase/changelog.xml`. Through the CLI I had to run it at this path `C:\Projects\[redacted]\src\main\resources` and in my `liquibase.properties` have this path instead `changeLogFile=db/liquibase/changelog.xml`